# Azure Sphere SDK Install Error 0xc0000005

Tags: azure-sphere

I'm on a Surface Book 3 running Windows 10 build 21292, attempting to install the Sphere SDK downloaded from [here](https://aka.ms/AzureSphereSDKDownload/Windows). The Azure Sphere splash screen pops up when I run the exe, but immediately goes away. In Event Viewer, I see the following error with exception code 0xc0000005:

```
Faulting application name: Azure_Sphere_SDK_20_11.exe, version: 20.11.0.58388, time stamp: 0x5e17c1e6
Faulting module name: unknown, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x00000000
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x006f0072
Faulting process id: 0x1c20
Faulting application start time: 0x01d6f00a874a864c
Faulting application path: C:\Users\rymcin\AppData\Local\Temp\{8D6BD41B-D05F-470D-97F4-D074C6E501D0}\.cr\Azure_Sphere_SDK_20_11.exe
Faulting module path: unknown
Report Id: 7064b0b0-caf1-4814-bdfb-ab2cde6421d1
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

I've tried rebooting, running the installer as admin, I've run the System File Checker (SFC), I've run chkdsk, no issues and no change. Everything else on this PC is working fine so I'm not sure where else to look.

Comment: Ryan, can you please archive and paste the logs from the %TEMP% folder dd_VC_AzureSphere_*.log?

Comment: Too long to paste here so created gist:  https://gist.github.com/ryankmcintyre/0b4071c67578c163daca8bb98b20dea8

Comment: Thanks Ryan. We released a new version of the Azure Sphere SDK : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/updates/azure-sphere-version-2102-is-now-available/ that we would love for you to try.

Beyond that, the Windows OS version is a bit confusing, so if the error persists, can you try running "systeminfo" from Command Prompt. In the gist you have above, it says Build 21327 which is a Server distro but above you mentioned build 21292 so we just want to confirm that also.

Comment: Thanks for following up Sudhanva. I still have the same error with the new SDK version. This machine is on Insider track so I get Windows updates frequently and am currently on build 21332. Systeminfo output is here in case that helps:  https://gist.github.com/ryankmcintyre/602ef56c927fee8d5225533f50b55357